# iOS JSON twitter response, convert to mutable

Tags: twitter, nsmutablearray, ios7, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app that is requesting a users list of followers. I would like to be able to change some of the data inside of the array I am getting back from twitter, but I can't seem to get it to become a proper mutable copy.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *theData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

NSMutableDictionary *TWData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
TWData = [theData mutableCopy];

NSMutableArray *data = [TWData objectForKey:@"users"];
```

The order this is in and doing a mutable copy FIRST is the last thing I tried. This is the code that throws an error:

```
[[data objectAtIndex:2] setObject:@"indeed" forKey:@"following"];
```

And here is the typical error message:

```
[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I understand WHY it is giving me the error, my question is how can I make EVERYTHING (all child dictionaries and array, and all of their child dictionaries and array, etc.) mutable so I can alter the data.

Any help is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy) from Core Foundation:

```
NSMutableDictionary* mutableData = (NSMutableDictionary*) CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFPropertyListRef) theData, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```

See the [CFPropertyList reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html) for more info. In particular, the [Property List Mutability Options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Property_List_Mutability_Options) can be used to control what is mutable in the returned copy.